# bootstrap 3.3.7 to 4beta2 : nav bar with razor not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Good day,

I have an asp.net MVC project, which uses bootstrap 3.3.7. I want to migrate from that version to 4 beta 2, for doing thatI have used bootstrap from [Get bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/) . But I can see that my nav bar is broken.
[image: broken navbar]

I am expecting to get something like this image( I got this nav bar from  a default  MVC project  in visual studio 2015,which uses  the bootstrap version3.3.7)
[image: bootstrap 3.3.7 navbar]

This is the navbar code for v 4 beta 2:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">&#x2630;</button>
        @Html.ActionLink("my page", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this for v3.3.7

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have included the scripts and css required using bundles:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Question:how can I fix my navbar? thank you.

Comment: What you mean "broken" You are not seeing the padding ? check the css files are loaded/ some other css is overwriting the css for those elements. Use the dev tools to find out what css is being applied and compare it with a working sample.

Comment: I mean by broken that the bootstrap styles are not working, even though I am using all the references needed.

Comment: You need to add the `.nav-link` class to your `a` tags, refer to the [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) for more information.

Comment: Did you resolve this, I have the same issue, except all of the formattings has disappeared.

Comment: I would suggest you to update to v4 using the nuget package, please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the bootstrap package using nugget, to version 4, this is the code for a basic navbar that translates from v.3 to v.4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fix fixed-top">

    <div class="container">
        @Html.ActionLink("My page icon", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        @Html.ActionLink("one link", "Index", "controll1", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Manage other things", "Index", "controll2", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                    </li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```